# How do I link files to download that were generated by a user using wkhtmltopdf during their current session

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am currently using wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf files and I would like to link the recently generated files for the user to download but after the user is finished with their session to delete them. Is there anyway to accomplish this without even having the file generated on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
exec("/path/to/binary/wkhtmltopdf   http://www.google.com /location/test.pdf");
$file = "/location/test.pdf";
$pdf = file_get_contents($file);

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdf));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($file).'";');
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
echo $pdf;

unlink($file);

?>
```

there could be an issues with files not beeing deleted so, i would add a cron job for deleting old ones.

Comment: When I echo the %pdf it doesn't link the pdf to download. It tries to print the contents of the pdf and I end up with the following being printed out. http://imgur.com/PwPs6

Comment: @seriot it shouldn't link, it should prompt the browser to download, which i thought was what you where asking how to do, but you are already showing a page, so that's not going to work. the above need to be a compete page alone.